# pandas dataframe groupby and then apply function

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I'd like to calculate the percentage of passing the level on everyday and every level

example dataset likes the following

| date | pass the level | level no | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 | true | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-05-05 | false | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-05-05 | true | 2 | 8 |
| 2021-05-10 | true | 2 | 5 |
| 2021-05-10 | false | 2 | 9 |

and the outcome I want looks

| date | level no | passing rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 | 1 | 0.7692 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.count, axis=0), columns=df.columns)


df.groupby(['date','level no'])['pass the level'].astype(int).mean()
```

You might first have to convert the boolean column strings so that the first letteer is a capital:

```
df['pass the level'] = df['pass the level'].str.upper()
```

Comment: but I'm looking for the passing rate which should be calculated by pass the level = true / true + false , groupby the level and date

Comment: By using the astype(int) you are changing the True/False to 1/0 and by taking the mean you will get the passing rate. Did you try running the code to see if it worked?

Comment: it gives me the output [ 0.5 1.0 0.5 ] I copied the output here .   date        level no
2021-05-05  1           0.5
            2           1.0
2021-05-10  2           0.5
Name: pass the level, dtype: float64

Comment: Sorry I dont understand.

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: As far as I can see that would be the result you want from your example dataset. What is wrong about it?

Comment: that's not equal to the passing rate. 10 pass and 3 fail to pass for 2021-05-05 and level 1, not 50% passing

Comment: Apologies. I understand what you are saying. I have changed my original answer. Please let me know if it works.